# Can radix sort reach exponential time complexity?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, radix-sort

For example, assume the input array is $$[121212,212121]$$
Say we are in base 10, so count sort will work in $O(n)$ time. We have 6 iterations which is approximately $n^2$. Is this a worst case example for radix sort?

If so, can I generalize this and say that given $k$ is the total number of digits, a worst case for the sort would be $\frac{k}{2}$ elements to sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ be the number of integers to sort, $M$ be the maximum integer, and $b$ be the chosen base.

Each execution of counting sort will take time $O(n + b)$ and the number of such executions is $O(\log_b M)$.
The total time complexity is then $O((n+b) \log_b M)$.

If you want to ensure that this complexity is exponential in the input size $s$ (which is at most $O(n \log_2 M)$) you need to select an exponential value of $b$, e.g., $b = 2^n$ if $M = O(2^{\text{poly}(n)})$.

If $b$ is constant (e.g., base $10$) then the time complexity of radix sort will always be $O(n \log M)$, which is always polynomial in the input size $s = \Omega(n + \log M)$ since $O(n \log M) = O( (n + \log M )^2 ) = O(s^2)$.
This bound is tight when $M = \Theta(2^n)$.

Comment: What about if M is unbounded? for example we have $n$ elements where $\log_bM$ is set to $n$ or $n^2$ etc. would we get $O(n^2)$ or $O(n^3)$ accordingly?

Comment: Yes. Keep in mind that $n$ is the number of input elements and not the size of the representation of the input, which is at least $\log M$ anyway.

Comment: And how would I counter this problem? if I change the basis to $M$ can I guarantee $O(n)$ time?

Comment: If you change the base to $M$ you'll get $O(M)$ time, i.e., you fall back into just running counting sort.  I think that, asymptotically speaking, the best thing you can do is to pick $b= n^\epsilon$ for any choice of a constant $\epsilon \in (0, 1]$ (for example, pick $b=n$). In this way  time required will be $O(n \frac{\log M}{\log n})$.

Comment: Yes I agree, also changing the basis could result in a larger time than $O(n)$ given the total number of digits is larger than $n$. Curious though, isn't there a solution for $O(n)$ complexity where $n$ denotes the number of (total) digits in the array? Or should I resort to a different algorithm altogether.

Comment: Assuming that arithmetic operations can be performed in $O(1)$ time, let $X$ be the set of elements to sort, and let $D$ be their total number of, say binary, digits.
Partition the numbers in $X$ into an ordered collection of sets $S_0, S_1,\dots$ depending on the number of digits they use.
This can be done in $O(D)$ time by starting with $S_0=X$ and, for $i=0,1,\dots$ moving to $S_{i+1}$ all the numbers in $S_i$ that are larger than or equal to $2^i$.

Comment: The problem now becomes sorting the numbers in the same set $S_i$ of the partition in time $O(|S_i| \cdot i )$. Radix Sort with base $2$ does the job since it performs $O(i)$ iterations each of which takes $O(|S_i|)$ time.